# MediaMTX RTSP container not proxying feeds

Tags: docker, portforwarding, docker-network

**Please note:** Even with port forwarding flags added this probelm persists, and so the other SO answers are not helping me here. I understand I am asking about the ope source [MediaMTX RTSP](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx) server here, but I believe this is a pure Docker question at heart; and as such, can be answered by anyone with Docker networking experience regardless of their experience with MediaMTX.

---

I am on a Mac laptop here. I am running MediaMTX via docker like so:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8554:8554 bluenviron/mediamtx:latest
2023/10/16 15:05:22 INF MediaMTX v1.2.0
2023/10/16 15:05:22 INF configuration loaded from /mediamtx.yml
2023/10/16 15:05:22 INF [RTSP] listener opened on :8554 (TCP), :8000 (UDP/RTP), :8001 (UDP/RTCP)
2023/10/16 15:05:22 INF [RTMP] listener opened on :1935
2023/10/16 15:05:22 INF [HLS] listener opened on :8888
2023/10/16 15:05:22 INF [WebRTC] listener opened on :8889 (HTTP)
2023/10/16 15:05:22 INF [SRT] listener opened on :8890 (UDP)
```

I can confirm that it is running:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
ef27229a41c4   bluenviron/mediamtx:latest   "/mediamtx"   19 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds             goofy_franklin
```

And `telnet` see it just fine:

```
telnet localhost 8554
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

But when I go to publish (write/stream) an MP4 to it via `ffmpeg` I get *broken pipe* errors:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i fireplace.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream     
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'fireplace.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 522 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 368x640, 448 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 368x640, q=2-31, 448 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe00:00:09.60 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x    /s speed=N/A    
[out#0/rtsp @ 0x128f15b00] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/rtsp @ 0x128f15b00] Error writing trailer: Broken pipe
frame=  305 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.10 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x    
video:560kB audio:80kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

When I run that command I get this output in the container logs:

```
2023/10/19 23:26:43 INF [RTSP] [conn 192.168.65.1:22506] opened
2023/10/19 23:26:43 INF [RTSP] [session f1b1b628] created by 192.168.65.1:22506
2023/10/19 23:26:43 INF [RTSP] [session f1b1b628] is publishing to path 'mystream', 2 tracks (H264, MPEG-4 Audio)
2023/10/19 23:26:50 INF [RTSP] [session f1b1b628] destroyed: torn down by 192.168.65.1:22506
2023/10/19 23:26:50 INF [RTSP] [conn 192.168.65.1:22506] closed: EOF
2023/10/19 23:26:53 INF [RTSP] [conn 192.168.65.1:22507] opened
2023/10/19 23:26:53 INF [RTSP] [session b7be9e08] created by 192.168.65.1:22507
2023/10/19 23:26:53 INF [RTSP] [session b7be9e08] is publishing to path 'mystream', 2 tracks (H264, MPEG-4 Audio)
2023/10/19 23:27:03 INF [RTSP] [conn 192.168.65.1:22507] closed: terminated
2023/10/19 23:27:03 INF [RTSP] [session b7be9e08] destroyed: session timed out
```

So it *appears* that `ffmpeg` is able to connect to the RTSP server, but not able to actually *send* anything to it.

**Can anyone spot where I might be going awry?**

Comment: No even with `-p 8554:8554` set the result is the same.

Comment: Using both `--network=host` and `-p 8554:8554` flags simultaneously can be redundant. Try running the Docker container without the `--network=host` flag, for testing, and making sure the port mapping is correct. `docker run --rm -it -p 8554:8554 bluenviron/mediamtx:latest`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC (+1) your suggestion nudged me one more step but I am still getting broken pipe errors in the `ffmpeg` output (see my edits). Thank you for this suggestion though!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup, my answer below also addresses your ffmpeg errors.  I was seeing the same issue during my testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

`docker run --rm -it --network=host -p 8554:8554`

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i fireplace.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`

View the stream with:

`ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`

**Explanation:**

Since you are running this on a mac, you are likely using Docker Desktop.  The [Docker Desktop documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/) has this to say about host networking:

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

Since you are running `docker run --rm -it --network=host -p 8554:8554 bluenviron/mediamtx:latest`, the `--network=host` option will override any port assignments you provide in the command.  Since this mode is not functional on Docker Desktop for mac, this means that your container will not be reachable.

To fix this, you will need to explicitly forward the ports you wish to use.  I was able to get the following to work on a mac:

`docker run --rm -it -p 8554:8554 bluenviron/mediamtx:latest` <- Starts the server

To test that this is working, I stream a continuous series of gray frames over the RTSP server with the following command:

`ffmpeg -readrate 1 -f lavfi -i color=c=gray -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`

`-readrate 1` limits ffmpeg from sending frames too fast, since the framerate we get with this synthetic video could cause issues.

`-f lavfi -i color=c=gray` generates gray frames continuously so we don't need to rely on any specific video for testing purposes

`-vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p"` sets the video format (25 FPS and 420p resolution)

`-c:v libx264` sets the codec to H264, one of the supported codecs for mediamtx's RTSP stream, per their [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/bluenviron/mediamtx).

`-f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp` sets the output format and transport protocol.  Note that your command above is missing `-rtsp_transport tcp`, which I found to be necessary in the same setup (macOS/docker/ffmpeg).  This is likely something you will need to add to your own ffmpeg command.

I was able to confirm that this stream was functional by viewing it with ffmpeg using the following command:

`ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`

*Edit for stream capture, per request*:

To capture the output of your stream back into a local file, you can use the following command:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -c copy fp-copy.mp4`

Since your original command will infinitely loop the fireplace.mp4 file you have, this will continue to capture until your disk is full.  To limit it to a specific duration, you can use the `-t` option on your output like so:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -c copy -t 60 fp-copy.mp4`

This will copy the first 60 seconds from the time you start streaming.  Increase it to whatever duration you would like.

You can also limit by file size instead of duration.  To do that, use:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -c copy -fs 100M fp-copy.mp4`

This will limit the output to 100MB.

Note that the first few seconds of your captured output may be black.  This comes from the period where ffmpeg is establishing a connection to the RTSP stream.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of trimming out this segment with an external tool, you can modify the command to:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -vf "trim=start=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -af "atrim=start=10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -t 20 fp-copy.mp4`

This new `-vf` option will trim the first 10 seconds from both audio and video.  Note that this is incompatible with the `-c copy` option, but it seems to work fine all the same.

Comment: Thanks @rnorris (+1) this is amazing thank you! Only one quick followup question. Although `ffplay` is working for me (on the read side) I'd like to copy the contents (read from the RTSP server) to a file called `fp-copy.mp4`. The idea is that whatever is published to the `mystream` stream gets copied into the `fp-copy.mp4` file. Do you know what `ffmpeg` command I could use for this? Thanks again so much!

Comment: No problem.  I have added some examples on how to do this at the end of the answer.

Comment: Saved my bacon with this -- cannot thank you profusely enough, cheers!